# Javascript Nested For Loop Array has hidden value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, variable-assignment, nested-loops

I have been using javascript to run some simple code that uses the leaflet.js library (in this instance, the particular function is mymap.layerPointToLatLng(), [here is the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-layerpointtolatlng) ).
I want to use some data of the form [[[x,y]],[[x,y]],...] (the format is particular for how leaflet.js handles polygons and multipolygons, this kind of format is what I have called 'dim=2'). I need to convert it into latitudes and longitudes (hence the previously mentioned function). Because I do this a lot, I wrote a function to do it for me:

```js
/*-Formatting functions*/
 function coordconvert(mapvar,array,dim){
  var temp1in=[],tempout1=[],temp2out=[];
  if(dim===1){
   for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    tempout1[i]=mapvar.layerPointToLatLng(array[i]);
   }
   return tempout1;
  }
  
  else if(dim===2){
   for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    temp1in=array[i];//each polygon
    console.log(i);
    console.log(temp1in);
    console.log(tempout1);
    //tempout1=[];//why do I need this line?
    for(j=0;j<temp1in.length;j++){
     console.log(tempout1);
     var checking = mapvar.layerPointToLatLng(temp1in[j]);
     tempout1[j]=mapvar.layerPointToLatLng(temp1in[j]);//each vertex of polygon
     console.log(j);
     console.log(tempout1);
     console.log(checking);
    }
    temp2out[i]=tempout1;//array of polygons
   }
   return temp2out;
  }
  else{
   console.log("Unable to process coordinate conversion on array");
   return
  }
  
 }
```

However, the 'if(dim===2)' section does not appear to be working correctly, hence all of the console.log lines.
In particular, the assignment `tempout1[j]=mapvar.layerPointToLatLng(temp1in[j]);` only appears to be working if I uncomment the line `//tempout1=[];//why do I need this line?`.

Using the console.log's, and viewed using Google Chrome, I get the following outputs:

[First few iterations of loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fio7a.png)
[Final iteration of the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ssM.png)

So as can be seen, The value (an object) of the final iteration is being included in the array of `tempout1` before anything has been assigned to it (I have tried removing the 'if(dim===1)' section, and renaming the tempout1 variable, with no luck), and is being hidden by Chrome(?!?!?!); The value is not being over-written during the loop (as can be seen by the comparison of `console.log(checking)` and `console.log(tempout1)`.

Why do I have to scrub the variable each time before the nested loop runs? And why is the value from the final iteration getting in before anything happens?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was quite simple - I wasn't declaring the loop variables properly (i.e. `for (var i=o;i<array.length;i++)`, rather than `for (i=o;i<array.length;i++)`) I'm not sure how this explains the behaviour of the Google Chrome console, but everything seemed much more stable afterwards.